# Error on installing .Net Core

Tags: installation, asp.net-core, .net-core

Trying to install .Net Core over VS Community 2015 update 3. I am stuck with the following error. Tried downloading and copying the msi file (AspNetCoreLocalFeed_.msi) manually but the destination folder as seen in the log file is being created dynamically so it doesn't work. Also attempted to install it manually. Nothing works.

Went through various threads on different websites on the installation errors but couldn't locate an answer for any similar issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
[23F8:2DD8][2016-11-08T22:02:58]w343: Prompt for source of package: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, payload: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, path: C:\Users\Faisal\Downloads\packages\AspNetCoreLocalFeed_.msi
[23F8:2DD8][2016-11-08T22:02:58]i338: Acquiring package: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, payload: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, download from: https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/5/7/557D02A5-C3D0-4EF6-A570-4F75CD0DA5BF/packages/AspNetCoreLocalFeed_.msi
[0190:0850][2016-11-08T22:05:07]e000: Error 0x80070490: Process returned error: 0x490
[0190:0850][2016-11-08T22:05:07]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to execute EXE package.
[23F8:3008][2016-11-08T22:05:07]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[23F8:3008][2016-11-08T22:05:07]i319: Applied execute package: DotNetCLI_x64, result: 0x80070490, restart: None
[23F8:3008][2016-11-08T22:05:07]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0190:0850][2016-11-08T22:05:07]i351: Removing cached package: DotNetCLI_x64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\
[23F8:2DD8][2016-11-08T22:05:07]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/5/7/557D02A5-C3D0-4EF6-A570-4F75CD0DA5BF/packages/AspNetCoreLocalFeed_.msi' to: 'C:\Users\Faisal\AppData\Local\Temp\{B803D3CE-B0AC-4779-8D29-E1D7B9070031}\AspNetCoreLocalFeed'
[23F8:2DD8][2016-11-08T22:05:07]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/5/7/557D02A5-C3D0-4EF6-A570-4F75CD0DA5BF/packages/AspNetCoreLocalFeed_.msi' to working path: 'C:\Users\Faisal\AppData\Local\Temp\{B803D3CE-B0AC-4779-8D29-E1D7B9070031}\AspNetCoreLocalFeed'
[23F8:2DD8][2016-11-08T22:05:07]e313: Failed to acquire payload: AspNetCoreLocalFeed to working path: C:\Users\Faisal\AppData\Local\Temp\{B803D3CE-B0AC-4779-8D29-E1D7B9070031}\AspNetCoreLocalFeed, error: 0x80070642.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an update in case it helps someone. Installation succeeded after reinstalling Visual Studio.